# Proof related to number of conjugates of an element of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

**Theorem**

Let G be a finite group and let a be an element of G . Then,$ |cl(a)|=|G:C(a)|.$

**Attempt**

Consider the function$T$ that sends the coset $xC(a)$  to the conjugate $xax^{-1}$.

$xC(a)=yC(a)$ which implies $y^{
-1}x \in C(a)$
which inturn implies $y^{-1}xa=ay^{-1}x$.Rearranging we get $xax^{-1}=yay^{-1}$. So **T is well defined.**
By reversing the argument ,we can see **T is one-one**. Clearly **T is onto**.

**Doubt**

Is my proof correct?

How to prove T **preserves operation**? Or does it preserves operation. (It is not required for the proof)

Comment: Why do you need $T$ to preserve an operation? All you need is that it's a bijection in order to conclude that the cardinalities of the two sets are equal.

Comment: My bad. I have edited the question.

Comment: Your proof is fine as written. Note that in general, $cl(a)$ and $G / C(a)$ aren't even groups, so it wouldn't make a lot of sense to ask whether $T$ preserves the group operation.

Comment: If $C(a)$ is replaced by center $Z(G)$ then the operation will be preserved right?

Comment: $T:gZ(G) \to \phi_g $where$ \phi_g= gxg^{-1}$